PHP Parse error: syntax error, unexpected token "{", expecting ";" while trying to replace create_function()
Could someone please help me check the syntax in the following code and why this is giving an error?
I've tried updating one of my Wordpress files to use the new syntax for function:
{
    $if = function(){
        return {$values['if']};
    };
    if ($if()) {
        $key = $oid;
        $id = get_queried_object_id();
        if ($id and $values['with-id']) {
            $key = "{$key}_{$id}";
        }
        break;
     }
}

instead of
{
    $if = create_function(
        '',
        "return {$values['if']};"
    );
    if ($if()) {
        $key = $oid;
        $id = get_queried_object_id();
        if ($id and values['with-id']) {
            $key = "{$key}_{$id}";
        }
        break;
    }
}

I tried various combinations of adding ";" , however I'm still getting the error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected token "{", expecting ";".

Https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting. You can [edit] your post so the code is readable

What version of php do you have?

Is this obfuscated code? An anonymous function just to test a value?

This part of the code:
$if=create_function('',"return {$values['if']};");if($if())

is just a complicated way to do a simple test:
if($values['if'])

